# How to upgrade Python from 3.9.5 to 3.9.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.9

I am using Ubuntu.
I have Python 3.9.5.
I would like to upgrade to 3.9.12.
How can install it?

I would prefer to install / update via sudo apt get. I don't have permissions to do a wget on the machine in question.

Comment: So what happens when you use `sudo apt get`?

Comment: I don't know and don't know how to look up, the particular command to upgrade it to 3.9.12. I tried this `sudo apt-get install python3.9.12`

Comment: Not a question for StackOverflow. You should ask the question on https://askubuntu.com 
And there you can also find a good answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get

Comment: I've highly recommend using `pyenv`, and not installing versions via `apt`. With `apt` your versions change again after the next update, and it's impossible to manage if you need different versions for different projects.

Comment: First at all, make sure you are not upgrading Ubuntu's built-in python. It's risky. You can try to install it from deadsnakes. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/682875).